# Should you accept an answer although its reasoning is incorrect?

Tags: discussion

Let's assume I have a question where someone has the correct answer but that user has the wrong reasoning for that answer (for riddles most of the time).

Should I accept these types of answers or just answer the question myself after too long?

Comment: I assume you're talking about this: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25004/what-am-i-this-time ? I've been puzzled by this one - I don't understand what you could *possibly* be looking for in the reasoning that isn't there. You even continued to give hints that indicated that the answer was right more than a week after the right answer, with more than sufficient reasoning, was posted.

Comment: The same is true of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25319/what-am-i-seen-everyday/25321#25321 and I will note this repeated "its not quite right" reasoning when people are answering your riddles is making me want to answer your riddles less - though that could just be me.

Comment: @JGreenwell, the fact the top answer cannot answer three of my clues makes the answer not quite right

Comment: In that case yes, in the first case no, and it hints towards a pattern when it starts to repeat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Really, the only valid answer to this question is, "If you want to."

Accepting an answer is entirely subjective. There is no "should," because it's entirely up to the asker of the question to decide which is the "best" answer.

That being said, what I often do in a situation like you're describing is to leave a comment indicating what's incorrect, and asking them to clean it up in order to get the check mark. Usually people are happy to keep trying to figure it out until everything falls into place.