# Which one should I accept?

Tags: discussion

Although the tittle suggests this is a duplicate, I feel that this is an unanswered question. (because [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4518/should-you-accept-an-answer-although-its-reasoning-is-incorrect) is assuming only one party, and [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/which-answer-should-i-accept) is a different problem.)

I've come across a few puzzles (specifically riddles with multiple clues)  that one person answers correctly but the clues wrong, or other way around.

Then later, another user answers the clues correctly, but based off of the first person's semi correct answer.

In this case who would be more appropriate to accept?

Comment: Your first link already answers this: [***Accepting an answer is entirely subjective. There is no "should," because it's entirely up to the asker of the question to decide which is the "best" answer.***](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4519)  Both links provide guidance on how to make that decision, but ultimately it's your call, based on whatever criteria you think makes one answer "best"—perhaps most complete, or most clear,or  most similar to the intended solution, or any other deciding factor you think most appropriate.